# How much smaller will be human body, when we hypothetically get of every space between particles

Tags: atoms, particle-physics

I had an interesting dream, where advanced civilization compress their body with technology, that turn off space betweens atoms/particles. They travel in small spaceship with billions citizens very effectively.

Crazy idea, but my question is how much smaller will the human body be, when we hypothetically get of every space between particles.

Comment: As the nucleus is about 10^5 times smaller than the atom, its volume is roughly 10^15 times smaller. If your volume is 100 liters (100 * 10^-3 m), then you'd shrink to 100 * 10^-18 cubic meters, or roughly a 3 micron sized cube. Note that your mass would not change, so the spaceship's acceleration would still be the same.

Comment: I've heard before that if you removed the space between every atom of every human on earth you could fit everyone into a ball the size of a marble, so I guess that means we'd be about one ten billionth of a marble each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing all the spaces between nuclei you are converting the matter to degenerate matter, which is what happens at the centre of a [neutron star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star). The density of matter at the centre of a neutron star is $6 - 8 \times 10^{17}$ kg/m$^3$. The density of a human body is around $10^3$ kg/m$^3$ (a bit less when you inhale and a bit more when you exhale) so your volume would decrease by a factor of about $7 \times 10^{14}$ and your height would decrease by the cube root of this or a factor of about $90,000$. Im my case (height $1.8$m) I would shrink to about $20\mu$m high.